# When is parametric line parallel to planes contained?

Tags: geometry, systems-of-equations, analytic-geometry

Given the system of parametric equations

$$x + y + kz = 1$$
$$x + y + kz = 3$$
$$2x + 2y + z(1+k) = 1$$
$$x + z = 0$$

I interpret this as two always (for each k) parallel planes:

$$x + y + kz = 1$$
$$x + y + kz = 3$$

And a line:

$$2x + 2y + z(1+k) = 1$$
$$x + z = 0$$

If my calculations are correct, I find that the line can never intersect the planes, but when is it only parallel and when does it actually lie on one plane? If it lies on a plane, how can I decide on which one?

Comment: what are exactly the equations of the plane and the line?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I am given the system of 4 equation in R^3 at the top of the question and asked to discuss it geometrically as k varies, I decided to think of the two top equations as one plane each and the bottom 2 as one line, but I could also have though of them as 4 planes or 2 lines

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner *2 planes, 1 equation for each plane

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner after some more calculations I get that the line lies on the first plane for k=2, and on the second for k=6 but I am not sure at all

Comment: Your sentence " the line can never intersect the planes" should be " the line can never intersect **both** planes".

Comment: Note that **parametric equations** has usually a very precise meaning in maths: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Parametric_equation. What you have is *equations with parameters*, which is different.

Comment: @Taladris yes, thank you I removed the extraneous tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ll easily find out that the line’s equation is 
$$(0,1/2,0)^t+\lambda(2,k-1,-2)^t.$$

Now that line is parallel to the planes if their normal vector, namely $(1,1,k)$, is orthogonal to the line’s direction vector $(2,k-1,-2)^t$, i.e., if $k=1$. But in this case $(0,1/2,0)^t$ doesn’t belong to either plane so line and plane are parallel and disjoint.

If $k\neq1$, line and plane will intersect, so your calculations seem to be defective.

Comment: What does your notation $$(0,1/2,0)^t$$ with the small `t` on top mean? To check if vectors are orthogonal I must set their scalar (dot) product = 0 correct?

Comment: Another small thing, if I get $$(0,1/2,0) - λ(2,k−1,−2)$$ it is the same because lambda can get any value it wants both positive and negative right?

Comment: @user3105485 Well, for your first question: it means the transpose, here $(0,1/2,0)^t=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1/2\\0\end{pmatrix}$.  For your second question: yes, the dot product here is $2+k-1-2k=1-k$.

Comment: After seeing that you put the line into parametric form, I got an idea as to how to calculate the intersection and put it in a self answer, could you check it please?

Answer (score 1):

(I was wrong, there can be points of intersection)

We can put the line in parametric form by choosing two arbitrary pairs of values for $x$ and $y$, calculating $z$ by putting them in the line cartesian equation, then calculating the difference vector between them, in formulas:

$$x = x_0 + t (x_1-x_0)$$
$$y = y_0 + t (y_1-y_0)$$
$$z = z_0 + t (z_1-z_0)$$

In order to find the points of intersection, after the line has been put into parametric form, we can substitute the values of x, y and z into the equation of the plane(s).

That finds the value of $t$ for which the intersection happens, we can then substitute that value in the parametric line equation we found before to find the actual point of intersection.

Comment: That’s definitely right.